# null is not an object (evaluating 'AppNavigator.router')

Tags: react-native, redux, router, react-native-router-flux

**

> I need help!! null is not an object (evaluating 'AppNavigator.router')

**

```js
/**
 * Created by nihalyorulmaz on 08/08/2017.
 */
import React from 'react';
import { Scene, Router} from 'react-native-router-flux';
import LoginForm from '../../components/components/LoginForm';


const RouterComponent = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Scene key = "login" component = {LoginForm} title = "Please Login"/>
        </Router>
    );
};

export default RouterComponent;
```

Comment: https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/857

Comment: thanks for your answer but ı cant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you need to wrap your scenes in a root scene `<Scene key="root">` which is not mentioned in documentation.

So your RouterComponent look like below:

```
const RouterComponent = () =>{

return(
    <Router>
        <Scene key="root" >
        <Scene key="login" component ={LoginForm} title="Please Login"/>
        </Scene>
    </Router>
);
};
```

Answer (score 4):

First check the version of your react-native-router-flux. If the version
is 3, wrap your `<Scene>` with `<Scene key="root" >`:

```
const RouterComponent = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Scene key="root">
                <Scene key="login" component={LoginForm} title="Please Login" />
            </Scene>
        </Router>
    );
};
```

For version 4, replace `<Scene key="root">` with `<Stack key="root">` and don't forget importing `import {Stack} from 'react-native-router-flux`:

```
import { Router, Scene, Stack } from 'react-native-router-flux';
    const RouterComponent = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Stack key="root">
                <Scene key="login" component={LoginForm} title="Please Login" />
            </Stack>
        </Router>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add your current scene in another scene with key="root"

```
<Scene key="root" >
        <Scene
            key="login"
            component={LoginForm}
            title="Please Login"/>
        </Scene>
```